# Dynamic multiple chart with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I try to create dynamic chart with VBA , for example I have 5 students I need to create 5 chart

for each students .

```
Sub Macro4()

Rows("2:2").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$2:$2")
Rows("3:3").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$3:$3")
Rows("4:4").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$4:$4")
Range("D12").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I create this using Macro only for test but I try do that as dynamically because if I have more then 100 students it will be difficult , etc..

I hope you guys help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next way, please. No need of any selection. Selection is useless, it only consumes Excel resources:

```
Sub AddCharts()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, ch As Shape, chartNo As Long
 Dim prevWith As Long, i As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet  'the sheet where the charts to be created
 'chartNo = 5
 chartNo = = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row - 1

 For i = 1 To chartNo
    Set ch = sh.Shapes.AddChart
    ch.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ch.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$" & i + 1 & ":$" & i + 1)
    ch.Chart.Parent.left = sh.Range("A1").left + prevWith 'here the first left chart position to be set
    prevWith = ch.Chart.Parent.width 'the chart width, the next one will be added to its right side
 Next i

 ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it is work fine  , but in this  "chartNo = 5 " can we do that as dynamic  ?

Comment: @programmer: Simply changing it in whatever nou need. If it would be an algorithm to calculate the necessary number, it will be calculate according to it. Do you have such an algorithm? For instance, should I understand that the number in discussion can be the filled rows number in Sheet1? If yes, I can immediately use this one to determine the number of necessary charts to be created. I adapted the above code to calculate ne necessary number according to A:A column records of "Sheet1". I decreased a unit, supposing that there is a column header, since the necessary rows start from the second.

Comment: @programmer: How many records do you have in "Sheets1"? It will adapt itself to the records in that specific worksheet. According to A:A last cell... Try adding another 'student' and see what happens... And does it 'give' an error or not? If yes, what error on which line?

Comment: this is the error message "Sub or Function not defined"

Comment: @programmer:  All what you have to do is to answer my questions! **On which code line does the error appear**?

Comment: can you please see the pic , Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just copying `chartNo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row - 1`? We lost hours... It is a character missing. I will adapt the code in some seconds... Adapted it. Please, check it now.

Comment: Since the error selected that word, it should be obvious that there is the error. Never mind, did you test the updated code?

Comment: yes but because it is first time use this , so I am not sure if the error is there , yes it is work fine thank you for your help and I am sorry for tack time ^_^

Comment: No problem... Before learning to program, it is mandatory to learn answering clarification questions. If you do not understand what you should do, **ask for clarification**... Anyhow, glad that the problem has finally been solved.

Comment: Welcome! Have a nice day, too!

Answer (score 0):

Change your macro like this:

```
Sub Macro4(startRow As String, stud As Long)
For k = 1 To stud
Dim constr() As String 
Dim cn As String
cn = ""
constr = Split(strtRow,":")
For Each c in constr 
  cn = cn & "$" & c & ":"
Next
cn = Left(cn, Len(cn) - 1)
Rows(strtRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!" & cn)
Dim str As String
str = ""
For each d in constr
  str = str & (CInt(d)+1) & ":"
Next
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
strtRow = str
Next
```

Now call like

```
Macro4("2:2",3)
```

Will do on 2:2 to 4:4

Comment: Thank you , but I cant runt his